# Alignment of text and image

Tags: html, css

I have some text and image which needs to be aligned as per attached image in HTML or CSS.

The image is in the following link
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLPFc.png

```
  <p>Q.1 Give the animals their names </p>
    <img src="firstq.png" id="abc" alt="profile picture" /> 

    <p>   1: LION      2:GIRAFFE   3: ELEPHANT   4: CROCODILE    5:ZEBRA    6:BEAR

              Choose from the following options
              (a)    A-6 B-4 C-3 D-2 E-5 F-1
              (b)   A-2 B-3 C-5 D-4 E-1 F-6
              (c)   A-1 B-2 C-3 D-4 E-5 F-6
              (d)   A-3 B-5 C-2 D-6 E-4 F-1
              Enter your Answer:
     </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy-but-sematically-bad solution: since you have it formatted, use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property

```
white-space: pre;
```

This way,

- New lines will be preserved
- Spaces and tabs will be preserved
- Text won't wrap

Comment: So you want me to use the tag <pre> in html. If yes then i used <pre> tag but its not working as intended

Comment: Ya its working with <pre>(not fully but still satisfied).But I want to know technically using CSS :D

Comment: No, just style your `<p>` element with CSS `white-space: pre`. Fore example, `<p style="white-space: pre">`, or create a stylesheet and use `#myParagraph{white-space: pre}` and `<p id="myParagraph">`.